# Vector vs Scalar velocity?

Tags: xna, mathematics

I am revamping an engine I have been working on and off on for the last few weeks to use a directional vector to dictate direction; this way I can dictate the displacement based on a direction. However, the issue I am trying to overcome is the following problem; the speed towards X and speed towards Y are unrelated to one another. If gravity pulls the object down by an increasing velocity my velocity towards the X should not change. This is very easy to implement if my speed is broken into a Vector datatype, Vector.X dictates one direction Vector.Y dictates the other (assuming we are not concerned about the Z axis). However, this defeats the purpose of the directional vector because:

```
  SpeedX = 10
  SpeedY = 15

  [1, 1] normalized = ~[0.7, 0.7]

  [0.7, 0.7] * [10, 15] = [7, 10.5]
```

As you can see my direction is now "scaled" to my speed which is no  longer the direction that I want to be moving in.

I am very new to vector math and this is a learning project for me. I looked around a little bit on the internet but I still want to figure out things on my own (not just look at an example and copy off it). Is there way around this? Using a directional vector is extremely useful but I am a little bit stumped at this problem. I am sorry if my mathematical understanding maybe completely wrong.

Comment: If you are moving at X=10, Y=15 then you are moving in the direction [10,15] = [2,3], not [1,1].  I'm not sure what you mean by this not being the direction you want to move in.

Comment: A direction vector tells the object which way its moving (and commonly which way its facing). Say for instance [0.7, 0.7] * MySpeed will yield a displacement vector so I can say MyPosition + MyDisplacementVector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[Obligatory link to They Might Be Giants' "Speed and Velocity", which covers the basic concepts of this issue.  And is probably a catchier tune than it has any right to be.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRb5PSxJerM)]

The gist:

- Speed is a scalar value stating how fast something is moving.
- Velocity is a vector value stating how fast something is moving **and** in what direction.

Velocity can be expressed as a normalised (ie: unit length) vector and a scalar 'speed', but for games it's normally much easier to just store the two multiplied together into a single velocity vector.

Once you're storing your velocity as a scaled vector, you can adjust the vertical component separately from the horizontal component.  For example, to apply gravity, you will normally just add `gravity * time` (or `-gravity`, depending on which direction your y axis goes and whether you express gravity as a positive or negative number).

If you are using velocity in this way, then you do not normally store speed at all.  If you need to do a calculation involving speed, you instead calculate it from the velocity by finding the velocity vector's length.

Comment: I just drew it all out on paper and came to the same conclusion; implementing it seems to underline what you are talking about. Thank you very much for clarifying it!